# symfony 3.4 - ManyToOne can't access to the data of an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have an entity call Category, an other call Product and one in the middle called CategoryProduct.

- I Have a relation OneToMany between Category and CategoryProduct:
  `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CategoryProduct", mappedBy="Catego", fetch="EAGER")` with the inversedBy in the CategoryProduct class (on the $catego).
- I Have a relation OneToOne between CategoryProduct and Product : `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="Category")` with the inversedBy in the Product class (on the $category).

inside my CategoryController i have a function like this :

```
public function getCategoryAction(Request $request)
{
    $category = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
                 ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
                 ->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse($category);
}
```

The return give the collection of entity Category, but the "sub entity" Product is empty. When I check the Token for debbug in Symfony I check the Doctrine section and the query works perfectly the data is load it's just doesn't here in my return. I can access to the data by using `$category->getProduct()` (it gives me a collection  of Product link to the category as I want), but still my Product subclass is empty. Does anyone know why ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate --skip-sync` and see if there are any mapping errors.
`

Comment: ...or an `doctrine:shema:update`

Comment: Apart from Carl's useful advice to validate your schema: Are you sure there can only be one CategoryProduct for each Product? Why use a "middle class" then in the first place? "inversedBy="Category"" means, you need to have a $Category property on your Product class. But it isn't a category really, it's a CategoryProduct.

Comment: I've Already try the schema validate / Update and there is no promblems there. I need the class in the middle for some information that I can't save anywhere else, the name of the property isn't relevant call it as you want. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 2):

Taking things from start your current problem is a typical Doctrine hydration thing.

By default Doctrine loads relationships lazily, that means that initially Doctrine provides a proxy Collection that does not hold any element in it, and loads the actual elements only when they are accessed in some way (e.g. when using a getter like getProduct()). That's why your Product collection seems empty.

You could easily change this by setting the fetch attribute in your association to EAGER:

```
// inside Category class
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", fetch="EAGER")
 */
 private $products;
```

However ultimately will not get your code working because when you are trying to json_encode an object with private properties, you will only get an empty json as a result. The solution to your problem is to use a custom way to serialize your object. The easiest (and probably) best solution is to use Symfony Serializer Component. BUT you should be aware that just using `$serializer->serialize($category, 'json');` will throw a circular reference exception. This will be caused because (as I guess) you also hold in your Product class a reference to Category like this:

```
// inside Product class
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 */
private $category;
```

As you can imagine, Symfony will try to serialize a category that has lots of products that have a category, that has lots of products... that's a circular reference.

To bypass this problem you should use serialization groups like this:

```
// inside your controller, supposing you are using autowiring to inject services:

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

public function getTariffsAction(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer)
{
    $category = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
             ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
             ->findAll();

    $categoryJson = $serializer->serialize($category, 'json', ['groups' => ['tariffs'] ]);

    return $this->json($categoryJson);
}
```

Then explicitly configure the attributes of your objects, you would like to get inside your entities like this:

```
// Category.php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
...
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @Groups({"tariffs"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Groups({"tariffs"})
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
 * @Groups({"tariffs"})
 */
private $product;

// any other attribute you want to include
```

And finally in your Product.php:

```
Product.php

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @Groups({"tariffs"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Groups({"tariffs"})
 */
protected $productName;

// do not include the reference to the category to avoid circular reference
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 */
private $category;
```

You can find more about the Serializer Component and serialization groups in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've tried the method you gave me, but the Json response is empty theres no property at all. The circular seems to be a good idea but one of my coworkers checked and said theres no problem there ... Thank you anyway for your help. If you have any other idea I'm hearing you ! :)

Comment: first of all you should dump the result of your query to see what you are actually getting before serialize.

Comment: If you try to json_encode an object like this, you will simply get an empty json. Circular reference will be created when trying to serialize using Serializer Component. I will update my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: When I tried to var_dump I saw what you meant, you're right there is a circular reference but I can't solve the problem with the groups, I've tried ...

Comment: what was your problem?

Comment: Nothing new, the return is like this `[{"id":1,"credits":0,"product":{},"statusId":2}]`.    The product field should be a Json array who contains the product table of my database

Comment: you have probably set your group attributes wrongly

Comment: Plus when I tried to add the line `@Groups({"tariffs"})` just to one parameters to see if it give me only this line, it doesn't ... I've copy/past the line you gave me

Comment: 1. have you installed and used symfony serializer properly? 2. have you added group annotations property? like this:
 (/**
   * @Groups({"tariffs"})
   */)

If yes, then what is the result of the $serializer->serialize(...)?

Comment: sorry i've forgot the return. I correct it and it gives me `[[]]`

Comment: please post your line in controller where you use serializer. also just dump the results inside the controller and post what you get, not the result from the json response

Answer (score 0):

Below my Controller update with the method you gave me.

```
public function getTariffsAction(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer) 
{
    $category = new Category();
    $category = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
            ->findAll();
    $categoryJson = $serializer->serialize($category , 'json', ['groups' => ['tariffs'] ]);
    return $this->json($categoryJson);
}
```

and when I dump the $category I obtain something that I can't paste because It's too much. With Postman it makes my computer bug a lot (one of my screen turn off) I have to reboot after that

Comment: Is $categoryJson an empty stringified array? Are you caching doctrine annotations somehow? Maybe trying to clear this cache will help: php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, you were absolutly right iiirxs it was the circular reference and I solved it with the groups as you said. (I used the FOSRestBundle for the groups easier than the native symfony methods)